# Syntax where clause in consultation with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I need to put a where clause in my query, but I'm not hitting the correct syntax.

```
       /*
        * Support listing and POSTing back Origem entities (e.g. from inside an
        * HtmlSelectOneMenu)
        */

         public List<Origem> getAll()
   {

      CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Origem> criteria = cb.createQuery(Origem.class);
        Root<Origem> root = criteria.from(Origem.class);
        return this.entityManager.createQuery(
                criteria.select(root).where())
                .getResultList();
   }
```

In my where clause want to bring all "origem" with id equal to the logged in user. 
Something like this:

Ex: `select * from origin where origem.id = loginBean.origem.getId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **criteria.add(Restrictions.eq())** to your criteria and I think if the id is unique you need to use `.uniqueResult()` to get the wanted result from your criteria, your code should be like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
Criteria cr = cb.createCriteria(Origem.class);
// add the restriction here
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", loginBean.origem.getId));
Origem root = (Origem) cr.uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use criteria.addRestrictions(Restrictions.eq("propertyName","propertyValue");

public List getAll(**long idFromLoginBeanOrigin**)
   {

```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Origem> criteria = cb.createQuery(Origem.class);
```

**criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("origem.id", idFromLoginBeanOrigin));**

```
    Root<Origem> root = criteria.from(Origem.class);
    return this.entityManager.createQuery(
            criteria.select(root).where())
            .getResultList();
```

}

I type it now do maybe have a typo, please check !